# Using R Package dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a table using `dplyr`. When I try I get an error that says "Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class quoted." Nothing is quoted in my script. Ideally I would like to create a table that is grouped by ScoutGrade, and shows the count of players for each designated ScoutGrade. I attached my script below:

```
PlayerSalariesProject %>%
  count(PlayerSalariesProject$WAR) %>%
  group_by(PlayerSalariesProject, PlayerSalariesProject$GradingScale)
```

Comment: You don't need the `PlayerSalariesProject$` inside any of the tidyverse functions.  Just provide the unquoted column name `PlayerSalariesProject %>% count(WAR)` count returns the summarised frequency count with 2 columns 1) WAR, 2) frequncy count 'n'.  So, you don't get other columns in the next step.  If you need to use `group_by`, probably you need `PlayerSalariesProject %>% group_by(WAR) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% group_by(GradingScale) %>% ...`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the unquoted column name inside the tidyverse function

```
library(dplyr)
PlayerSalariesProject %>%
    group_by(WAR) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>% 
    group_by(GradingScale, n)  %>%
    summarise(meanWAR = mean(WAR))
```

As `summarise` only returns the columns summarised along with the grouping variables, we can use `mutate` and then do another `group_by`

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is the first time I'm using dplyr. So If I wanted to create a column that is the average of WAR, would I use mutate then too?? PlayerSalariesProject %>%
  count(ScoutGrade)                                                                                                              This gives me a count by Scout Grade but I also want it to give me the average WAR in the same table...if that makes sense

Comment: @elehr22  If you want a single row for each group, use `summarise` (updated the answer) or if you want to create a column in the dataset, `mutate`